# cannot resolve method of() , when i try to instantiate ViewModelProviders

Tags: android

cannot instantiate viewModelProviders in activity

```
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private NoteViewModel noteViewModel;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        noteViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NoteViewModel.class);
        noteViewModel.getAllNotes().observe(this, new Observer <List<Note>> () {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List <Note> notes) {
                //update RecyclerView
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onChanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: can you link your gradle dependencies?

Comment: `implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `Android x` make sure you implement those dependencies in your build.gradle file

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:compiler:$lifecycle_version"
```

Then make sure you indicate those properties in your `gradle.properties`

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Finally you should check if you import `AppCompatActivity` from Androidx not support

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides Amine's answer i think it's worth checking if you are using the proper viewmodel provider.
`ViewModelProvider` does **not** have .of()... However, `ViewModelProviders` notice the s in the end has the method .of().